# How to use variables with MongoDB $lookup

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

Let's say I have 3 collections, `cars`, `bikes`, `vehicles`.

`cars` *collection as:*

```
{
  {
    "_id": "car1",
    "carBrand": "Audi",
    "color": "blue"
  },
  {
    "_id": "car2",
    "carBrand": "BMW",
    "color": "white"
  }
}
```

`bikes` *collection as:*

```
{
  {
    "_id": "bike1",
    "bikeBrand": "Audi",
    "color": "red"
  },
  {
    "_id": "bike2",
    "carBrand": "BMW",
    "color": "white"
  }
}
```

*and the* `vehicles` *collection actually just has references to `cars` and `bikes` collections as*

```
{
  {
    "_id": "vehicle1",
    "vehicleType": "cars",
    "vehicleId": "car1"
  },
  {
    "_id": "vehicle2",
    "vehicleType": "cars",
    "vehicleId": "car2"
  },
  {
    "_id": "vehicle3",
    "vehicleType": "bikes",
    "vehicleId": "bike1"
  },
  {
    "_id": "vehicle4",
    "vehicleType": "bikes",
    "vehicleId": "bike2"
  },

}
```

I'd like to join the `vehicles` collection with `cars` and `bikes` collections. I tried to set `"$vehicleType"` as a variable to `$lookup`'s `from` field. However it does not work as I expected. It simply does not join the tables. No errors.

```
db.collection.aggregate([{

  $lookup: {
      from: "$vehicleType",
      localField: "vehicleId",
      foreignField: "_id",
      as: "vehicleDetails"
  }

}]);
```

I was expecting to have a result something like this

```
{
  {
    "_id": "vehicle1",
    "vehicleType": "cars",
    "vehicleId": "car1",
    "vehicleDetails": {    
      "_id": "car1",
      "carBrand": "Audi",
      "color": ""
    }
  },
  {
    "_id": "vehicle2",
    "vehicleType": "cars",
    "vehicleId": "car2",
    "vehicleDetails":    {
      "_id": "car2",
      "carBrand": "BMW",
      "color": "white"

  },
  {
    "_id": "vehicle3",
    "vehicleType": "bikes",
    "vehicleId": "bike1",
    "vehicleDetails":    {
      "_id": "bike1",
      "bikeBrand": "Audi",
      "color": "red"
    }
  },
  {
    "_id": "vehicle4",
    "vehicleType": "bikes",
    "vehicleId": "bike2",
    "vehicleDetails":    {
      "_id": "bike2",
      "carBrand": "BMW",
      "color": "white"
    }
  },

}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If cars and bikes don't have common IDs, you can sequentially lookup in separate arrays, then combine them with [$setUnion](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setUnion/):

```
db.vehicles.aggregate([
  {$lookup: {
      from: "cars",
      localField: "vehicleId",
      foreignField: "_id",
      as: "carDetails"
  }},
  {$lookup: {
      from: "bikes",
      localField: "vehicleId",
      foreignField: "_id",
      as: "bikeDetails"
  }},
  {$project: {
     vehicleType: 1,
     vehicleId: 1,      
     vehicleDetails:{$setUnion: [ "$carDetails", "$bikeDetails" ]}
  }},
  {$project: {
      carDetails:0,
      bikeDetails:0,
  }}
]);
```

Otherwise you will need to use [$facet](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/facet/) to filter vehicles by type before lookup:

```
db.vehicles.aggregate([
   {
     $facet: {
         "cars": [
            {$match: {"vehicleType": "cars"}},
            {$lookup: {
               from: "cars",
               localField: "vehicleId",
               foreignField: "_id",
               as: "vehicleDetails"
             }},
         ],
         "bikes": [
            {$match: {"vehicleType": "bikes"}},
            {$lookup: {
               from: "bikes",
               localField: "vehicleId",
               foreignField: "_id",
               as: "vehicleDetails"
             }}
         ]
     }
   },
   {$project: {all: {$setUnion: ["$cars", "$bikes"]}}},
   {$unwind: "$all"},
   {$replaceRoot: { newRoot: "$all" }}
])
```

Comment: Thank you. How about performance? I suppose, this would join `cars` and `bikes` collections regardless of the `vehicleType`. Would there be a way to filter based on `vehicleType` before `$lookup`?

Comment: yes, as I was saying in more general case you need to employ facets. I have updated the answer with code snippet.